# Code working in firefox but not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, opera

http://eddiela.github.io/JOB
this link is working on google chrome,firefox,opera but when i downloaded all the files from source it was working on firefox but does not work on chrome either or opera

Comment: Include the code here

Comment: Also specify what exactly isn't working, and any errors you are seeing.

Comment: If the problem is with getUserMedia not working, you need to access your site over https

Comment: This is  cross-origin problem ( blocked by chrome ) see here [Chrome c-o](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)